# Accessing tumblr posts with JSON/JSONP

Tags: javascript, json, api, jsonp, tumblr

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dEavg/) is a fiddle I'm working on.

I'm trying to load the posts from `ftsstudios.tumblr.com` with JSONP, and then using that data on a post reader.

```
get_data = function (data) {
    FTSPosts.raw = data;
};
$.ajax({
    url: "//api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/ftsstudios.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=myapikey&limit=20&jsonp=get_data",
    dataType: "jsonp"
});
```

The above snippet should set `FTSPosts.raw` to the response obtained.

The problem with this is that the `data` retrieved by `get_data` returns `undefined`.

What is the problem?

Comment: if you use jsonp as a dataType you don't need to specify the callback in the API url (jquery does what it has to do). 
So you should just do:
`$.ajax({url: "...", dataType: "jsonp"}).success(get_data);`

Comment: @charly, so `$.ajax({url:"//api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/ftsstudios.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=myapikey&limit=20",dataType: "jsonp"}).success(get_data);` ?

Comment: yep think it should work

Comment: You do know that jsonp requests are asynchronous

Comment: @charly with that approach, `response` remains undefined.

Comment: the URI i used will have a response of `get_data({tumblr things})`, so maybe it is supposed to be ran as an external script?

Comment: Ha tumblr doesn't take `callback` but `jsonp` maybe try: `$.ajax({url:"//api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/ftsstudios.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=myapi‌​key&limit=20",dataType: "jsonp", jsonp: 'jsonp'}).success(get_data);`

Comment: @charly produces the same output

Comment: why would it return `undefined` anyways

Comment: well this works: `http://jsfiddle.net/mv9J7/` (though I don't have an API key)

Comment: @charly i used my api key and it works. the thing is, on my original fiddle, it won't. look, i updated it: http://jsfiddle.net/dEavg/5/

Comment: it seems to be a problem with the way it is formatted?

Comment: Here is your corrected fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8MKE4/1/
There was a few problems that I corrected. The way you do OO is wrong you should read about it (prototypal inheritance is my favourite and easiest to understand). I'll comment your previous fiddle to explain where it was wrong.

Comment: @charly thank you, and i'll make sure to do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a few errors in the code. But the answer to the question is:

```
get_data = function (data) {
   FTSPosts.raw = data;
};
$.ajax({
   url: "//api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/ftsstudios.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=myapikey&limit=20",
   dataType: "jsonp",
   jsonp: "jsonp"
}).success(get_data);
```

2 things:

- If you set the data type to "jsonp" you don't need to provide in the url the callback (jquery does it internally)
- The parameter for the callback is by default "callback" if you need to change it add as an option `jsonp: "the_parameter_callback"`