# getting posts from tumbler using api

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, tumblr, posts

i wan to get posts from tumbler and display in my website blog .

```js
$.ajax({
  "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/rexsmith731.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=myapikey",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(results){
    $("h1").html(results.response.blog.title); 
    }
});
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/rexsmith731.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=myapikey",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(avatar){
      console.log(avatar);
 $(".avatar").attr('src', avatar.response.avatar_url); 
    }
});


$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/rexsmith731.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=myapikey",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(posts){
      var postings = posts.response.posts;
      console.log(postings);
      var text = '';
for (var i in postings) {
 var p = postings[i];
text += '<li><img src=' + p.photos[0].original_size.url +'><a href='+p.post_url+'>'+p.source_title+'</a></li>';
}
$('ul').append(text);
    }
});
```

```css
ul img {
  
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  padding: 10px;
  text-transform: Uppercase;
  font-family: helvetica;
}
```

```html
<h1></h1>
<img src="" class="avatar">
<span class="followers"></span>
  <ul>
    
  </ul>
```

it is returning page title but not avatar and posts ? what error i am making ?
i am using consumer key as a API key. any other way that i can display my tumbler data into my website blog ?

Comment: What does `console.log(postings)` log?

Answer (score 1):

there is a problem I have found:

this line `for (var i in postings) {` (iteration over keys and indices) does not work well with `var p = postings[i];`. Either use `for (var i = 0; postings.length; i++) { var posting = postings[i]; // ...` or use `for (var posting of postings) { // ...`

if the code still won't work, share what the code does then

EDIT:
I have also noticed that your jsonp request slightly differs from what I have found here: [Accessing tumblr posts with JSON/JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133509/accessing-tumblr-posts-with-json-jsonp). Would the answer there perhaps solve your problem?